# A fatal error when game ends

Tags: java, eclipse

I have stumbled upon that error. I have had some similar error which had crash log and were way better described so i could figure out what was wrong. But how to solve this?

edit: it is from the game that i am making. Actualy it's done i have just added some bonus features and then that happened.

edit: also a question: doest this kind of error implies to my mistake while coding or as comments suggests: computer software? Or it can be either?

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000056813d30, pid=5648, tid=7160
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64     compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [atio6axx.dll+0x243d30]
```

Comment: What "game" are you talking about? Is this an application you are writing or someone else's code?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your graphics card driver. Try to update your draphics driver (AMD Catalyst), this *might* help. Also, an update of your JVM could help.

Comment: @BVB: it's form i hame i am making. I have edited the question

Comment: @exception1: i will try that tomorrow, ty. Need to go to work after 5 hrs so no time now

Comment: Holy crap I have no idea what you are saying. Is this what happens when the game completes, or when it exists? What is the "way longer" console text?

Comment: It is happening when end game screen was called.

Well my english is in progress. What i meant was that when i have got that kind of errors i have got way more data. Also the eclipse has saved the crach file so it could be sended. But here are just that few lines...